# dpkg-buildpackage ignores Vcs-Git in debian/control

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I'm building a Debian package and have the following `debian/control` file:

```
Source: custom-package
Section: custom
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Dusan Rychnovsky <dusan.rychnovsky@gmail.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0)
Standards-Version: 3.9.2
Vcs-Git: git://github.com/project/custom-project.git

Package: custom-package
Architecture: amd64
Section: custom
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: Custom package description.
```

When I run `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`, the `DEBIAN/control` file in the generated `.deb` package looks as follows:

```
Package: custom-package
Version: 0.1-1
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Dusan Rychnovsky <dusan.rychnovsky@gmail.com>
Installed-Size: 6528
Depends: libatlas3gf-base, libc6 (>= 2.7), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libhdf5-openmpi-1.8.4, libjpeg62 (>= 6b1), libopenmpi1.3, libprotobuf7, libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0)
Section: custom
Priority: optional
Description: Custom package description.
```

It seems that `dpkg-buildpackage` is ignoring the `Vcs-Git` tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. The `VCS-*` fields are for source packages, not binary packages. Compare:

```
$ apt-cache showsrc php5 | grep -i git
Vcs-Browser: http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=pkg-php/php.git
Vcs-Git: git://anonscm.debian.org/pkg-php/php.git
$ apt-cache show php5 | grep -i git   
$
```